# Sharepoint--->>RSS Feeds. Filtering according to User Requirement

Tags: sharepoint, filter, rss

I need some help with RSS Feeds.We have a SharePoint site and We have used The RSS Viewer webpart to show Feeds. My requirement now, is to filter RSS Feeds according to user requirements, such that the user can search for only those feeds he/she thinks is relevant.The search should be keyword based. I have heard of Feed reader and Yahoo Pipes but we do not want to use these. Is there another option pro grammatically possible?? Do I need to build a custom RSS Viewer Web part? 
Any thoughts/ideas/suggestions will be greatly appreciated!!Please do mention some examples/articles of relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a [Filter Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-filter-web-parts-HA010033786.aspx) and make your RSS Viewer read data from it?

Comment: Thanks a lot Nemanja! That could be a solution, only thing is how do I add a filter web part.Our web part gallery doesn't contain filter web parts.Any articles/examples would be greatly appreciated.